# Pie Chart : with text value in columns

Tags: excel, excel-charts

want to draw Pie Chart with following data

```
  Box   |  Status
  ---------------------------
  Box1  |  Scan
  Box2  |  Index
  Box3  |  None
  Box4  |  None
  Box5  |  Process
  Box6  |  Process
  Box7  |  Scan
```

Expected result like this[image]

Comment: You're not saying much about what you tried and where you searched. Do you expect some vba solution? Then you must learn a little about it for yourself and show us where you're blocked, I think, otherwise it looks like we do your job. And maybe explain a little better what's your intent, e.g. why box2 is pointing to "Process" instead of "Index"?

Comment: @J.Chomel  i want to drow a pie chart to show the status of the boxes i have. none means not started yet, scanned means converted physical box to electronice copies, indexed means data entry, process means its done every thing. i wanna know is there any way to draw chart with non numerical value. thats all

Comment: Then a-burge's suggestion looks great.

Answer (score 1):

Create a third column with the value of 1 in each cell. Sort on column status. Insert pie chart and change the background colour of areas accordingly while removing line.

If the 'Box' information is not needed, you could create a separate 'Label' table with [Index, check, process, none, scan] and do a countif([status],'Label').

ps. well down with the drawing, you'll never be able to match that authenticity in Excel, unfortunately.